# Schedule a queue via putdata and execute it discontinuously via multiple triggers

Tags: matlab, data-acquisition

I am using the Matlab data acquisition toolbox to control the output of a National Instruments device (NI USB 6229). So far I am able to create output objects via `analogoutput` and 
`addchannel`, queue my data via `putdata`, and start the data output via a `trigger`.

However, once triggered, the queue is executed as a whole and I was wondering whether it is possible to execute only a certain number of samples.

Hence, imagine that I queue 10.000 samples via `putdata`, say. Then, each time a trigger occurs, only 1.000 samples are executed until the queue is empty (i.e., such that the queue is empty after 10 triggers).

**Would that be possible with Matlab's data acquisition toolbox, and if yes, how?**

Comment: Could you give some more info on why you want this to happen? Given several problems the solution could either be to group the samples in batches of 1000 before or after triggering.

Comment: The main reason was the timing issue, that is, the delay caused by matlab when queuing/sending the data after a trigger was received. I solved the problem now by utilizing the stopFcn-callback to queuing the data which are then  put out after the trigger occurs. However, I would be still interested in having a solution for the scenario described above.